# I want to make some dependency changes of a jar(1) into pom.xml of a another jar(2)

Tags: java, maven

I want to make some dependency changes of a jar(1) into pom.xml of a another jar(2) so that the jar2 use the previosu version or mentioned version of jar 1 as a dependency. Can any one help me here

For Example
X.jar

```
<dependency>
  <Groupid>abc
  <Version>2
</dependency>
```

Y.jar contain dependency of X. jar into POM 
Now i want to make changes for X. jar from version 2 to 1 throughout

Comment: So what i try i open my .m2 folder and make changes of version in jar 2 for dependency as version 1 and its working fine
 but this wont help us to centralize as everyone have to make this changes on their locals if many people are working on this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, it is about transitive dependency for Y.jar through X.jar to something called "abc" version 1 instead of version 2.

If so, just put direct dependency on "abc" version 1 into Y.jar and Maven will override/omit transitive dependency from X.jar

If you will get something about conflict between them you can add `<exclude>` for "abc" version 2 into dependency for X.jar in Y.jar pom - just to be sure "abc" version 2 will never come to the picture from X.jar pom.

Comment: Yes that i can changes directly into my m2 but that wont be able to use for others

Comment: I did not get it. What does it mean "that wont be able to use for others"? any project which want to use same version must do the same. Or you can make another parent project (as "pom" type) on top of Y.jar which other will use too. Other way is to create "bom" project with that override you and others will use instead of dependency directly on X.jar

Comment: Let me explain a bit here
So I have common jar, i use this dependency in project so that it could be download through nexus 
now after got downloaded, i go to m2 folder and check pom of common jar where common jar again have a dependency on xyz jar of version2, now i want to changes xyz version from 2 to 1 in common jar pom. How to get this done?

Comment: only what I can say don't even think to do that. It will be a mess in your projects. Follow Maven structures make additional pom/bom, direct dependency, set exclusions properly etc. (it seems you did not get my answer and comments) sorry...